# How to fix what dates your dataframe includes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing, reindex

I have a dataframe whereby I'm trying to get data from today (-5) days until the end of next month.

In the case of today this would be;

```
ix = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=datetime(2020, 6, 05), end=datetime(2020, 7, 31), freq='D')
df.reindex(ix)
```

If I wanted to automate this is there any function I can take advantage of?

I've tried

```
startdate = pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.DateOffset(days=5)
enddate = pd.to_datetime('today', format) + MonthEnd(2)

ix = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=startdate, end=enddate, freq='D')
df.reindex(ix)
```

..but does now seem to be working. 
Any help appreciated!

Comment: By *now* you mean *not*? What is the error? Did you mean `ix = pd.date_range(start=startdate, end=enddate, freq='D')`? And btw. I think you don't need to provide a format with 'today'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was close, I think the main issue is you are constructing a `DatetimeIndex` incorrectly: it doesn't take a `start` or `end` parameter (see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html)).  Also agree with @MrFuppes about `format` being unnecessary.

I think you want `pandas.date_range`, which still returns a `DatetimeIndex`

```
startdate = pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.DateOffset(days=5)
enddate = pd.to_datetime('today') + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(2)

ix = pd.date_range(startdate,enddate,freq='D')
```

This seems to work for me, and can be used for reindexing.  You could also call the `floor` method on your start and end dates if you just want to get dates without the specific time of day the code was run:

```
ix = pd.date_range(startdate.floor('d'),enddate.floor('d'),freq='D')
```

Comment: ah was so close! this is perfect, thanks very much!